# shell script (ksh) + compare sign as param is it possible?

Tags: ksh

Subject shell script

if I perform compare on the following

```
 [[ 2 -eq 2 ]] && print OK
```

I get OK

But how to compare if the "-eq" is in my param

for example

param="-eq"

```
  [[ 2 $param 2 ]] && print OK
```

Obvious that not illegal

but I wonder if it possible anyway with some changes??
Lidia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but you could use `eval` for this:

```
eval [[ 2 $param 2 ]] && print OK
```

Comment: nice -:) and what about if i perform ( if [[ ....... ]] then ) in this case where I need to put the eval command?

Comment: @lidia: You can put the `eval` right after the `if`: `if eval [[ ... ]]`

Answer (score 1):

The `[[` construct was designed precisely so that operators (such as `-eq`) must be specified directly, to avoid strings coming from parameter expansion being accidentally interpreted as parameters.

Use `[`, which is an ordinary command with fairly similar syntax to `[[`. Since it's an ordinary command, parameter expansion happens normally.

`[ 2 $param 2 ] && print OK`